# Best means to parse through multiple subelements within XML

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xmltodict

I am attempting to use xmltodict to parse through XML in to hopes of eventually converting to a more readable table format for others. I have been able to get through most of the XML but when I come to an element with multiple subelements, I feel I am chasing my tail. My hope is to use panda with the values I extract from the XML...

Here is a sanitized version of the XML I am attempting to parse:

```
  <batchConfiguration>
    <batchJob name="BATCHJOB1">
      <className>batchJob1</className>
      <schedule>Y</schedule>
      <interval>300</interval>
      <systemControlled>N</systemControlled>
    </batchJob>
    <batchJob name="BATCHJOB2">
      <params>
        <param name="QueueName1">batchQueue1</param>
      </params>
      <className>batchJob2</className>
      <startTime>02:10:00</startTime>
      <schedule>N</schedule>
      <daysOfTheWeek>YYYYYYY</daysOfTheWeek>
      <systemControlled>N</systemControlled>
    </batchJob>
    <batchJob name="BATCHJOB3">
      <params>
        <param name="ignoreErrors">Y</param>
        <param name="batchSize">1000</param>
      </params>
      <className>classyBatchJob</className>
      <schedule>Y</schedule>
      <interval>90</interval>
      <systemControlled>N</systemControlled>
    </batchJob>
  </batchConfiguration>
```

My thought was I could somehow loop through the lines where there are multiple "params". I can return a single line of "params" but stumped when there are multiple. Here is my code to date. It has pieces parts where I try to figure things as I go. The XML is read from a file...

```
import xmltodict as xml
import pprint

#File to parse
fileptr=open(r"FileIRead.xml")

# Show raw XML text file data
raw_file= fileptr.read()
# print(raw_file)

# Create an XML dictionary
xml_dict=xml.parse(raw_file)
pprint.pprint(xml_dict)

xml_dict1=xml.parse(raw_file)['batchConfiguration']['batchJob']
pprint.pprint(xml_dict1)
# pprint.pprint(xml_dict['batchConfiguration']['batchJob'])

# https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

for bJ in xml_dict1:
    bJName=bJ['@name']
    print(f"Name: {bJ['@name']}")
    print(bJName)
    try:
        print(f"Interval: {bJ['interval']}")
    except:
        print("Interval: N/A")
    try:
        print(f"Scheduled: {bJ['schedule']}")
    except:
        print("N/A")
    try:
        print(f"Start Time: {bJ['startTime']}")
    except:
        print("Start Time: N/A")
    try:
        print(f"End Time: {bJ['endTime']}")
    except:
        print("End Time: N/A")
    try:
        # This works fine to return only a single element. With multiple it fails.
        print(f"Params: {bJ['params']['param']['@name']} - {bJ['params']['param']['#text']}")
    except:
        print("Params: N/A")
    try:
        print(f"Classname: {bJ['className']}")
    except:
        print("Classname: N/A")
    try:
        print(f"DaysOfWeek: {bJ['daysOfTheWeek']}")
    except:
        print("DaysOfWee: N/A")
    try:
        # Attempt to get all parameters single or multiple
        xml_dict2=xml.parse(raw_file)['params']['param']
        pprint.pprint(xml_dict2)
        for bJ1 in xml_dict2['params']['param']:
            print(f"--- {bJ1['@name']}")
    except:
        print("It no worky")
```

Edit:
By request... The output I have been able to get is:

```
Name: BATCHJOB1
Classname: batchJob1
... (etc)
```

My end goal is to take the output and put it into column format something like this:

```
Name            Classname    ...
BATCHJOB1       batchJob1
```

"N/A" would be placed where the element does not exist or has no value.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your expected output given your sample xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmltodict` is only returning a dict when it is one parameter, but a list when it is two or more.  There is a `force_list` parameter to `.parse` that allows keys to be indicated that should always be lists.

You could use:

```
xml_dict1 = xml.parse(raw_file, force_list=('param',))['batchConfiguration']['batchJob']
```

Then:

```py
try:
    for p in bJ['params']['param']:
        print(f"Params: {p['@name']} - {p['#text']}")
except KeyError: # recommend never use bare 'except'
    print("Params: N/A")
```

Comment: Thank you, this does output the subelement values. As a side, I was not sure I could leave KeyError blank so I did not add them to my except lines.

Comment: @gritts Using the error expected makes sure you don't accidently ignore other errors.  For example, `NameError` is raised if you misspell a variable (`bj` vs. `bJ`) but would be silently ignored.

Comment: This answer worked best for me in terms of the information returned. I was able to capture the subelement values along with their corresponding element values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this can be accomplished by [using pandas.read_xml()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_xml([your_xml]).iloc[:,0:2]
```

Output, based on your sample xml:

```
      name      className
0   BATCHJOB1   batchJob1
1   BATCHJOB2   batchJob2
2   BATCHJOB3   classyBatchJob
```

Comment: Not what I was thinking, honestly didn't know you could do that. I am thinking of using panda to format the results where I can export them to a .csv file. (eventually) I should say using panda here was a means to learn more new stuff. Thank you, I will look at this as an option as well.

Comment: I worked with this solution a bit and prefer how this outputs the XML converted to tables. Further tinkering I was able to return as comma delimeted values. I would like this to return the subelements (params) as well but not sure how to go about that with this approach.

Comment: @gritts It's probably possible to do that, but per SO policy, you should post it as a separate question.